# Postfix Submission port issue

Tags: port, postfix, mailman

I have setup **postfix+mailman** on my **debian** server and i have an  issue with postfix **submission port**.
My ISP **blocks SMTP** on port 25 to prevent *spams and i must to use submission 
port (587).
I have uncomment the following line from master.cf (/etc/postfix/) but nothing happens.

> **submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd**

This is my mail logs file when i try to invite a user to mailman list

```
Nov  6 00:35:34 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1763]: C90BF1060D: from=<mailman-bounces@mydebianserverdomain.com>, size=1743, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  6 00:35:34 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1763]: DF54B10608: from=<root@mydebianserverdomain.com>, size=488, nrcpt=1 (queue active) Nov  6 00:35:34 myhostname postfix/qmgr[1763]: 80F0D10609: from=<root@mydebianserverdomain.com>, size=483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  6 00:35:55 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:35:55 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:35:55 myhostname postfix/smtp[2271]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:16 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:16 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:16 myhostname postfix/smtp[2271]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.143.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:37 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.141.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:37 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.141.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:37 myhostname4 postfix/smtp[2271]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.141.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:58 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.64.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:58 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.64.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:36:58 myhostname postfix/smtp[2271]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.64.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2269]: C90BF1060D: to=<GmailAccount@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=23711, delays=23606/0.03/105/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2271]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2270]: DF54B10608: to=<GmailAccount@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=23882, delays=23777/0.03/105/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Nov  6 00:37:19 myhostname postfix/smtp[2271]: 80F0D10609: to=<GmailAccount@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=23875, delays=23770/0.04/105/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.142.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU) biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com,localhost
relayhost =
relay_domains = $mydestination, mail.mydomain.com
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
```

**master.cf**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Are you intending to receive emails on this server or only to send them?  If you are only sending, where do bounces and replies go?  Port 25 is fairly fundamental to the function of a mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Submission has nothing to do with ***sending*** mail to non-standard ports.

For this, configure a relayhost that connects to the appropriate remote IP and port.

For example:

```
relayhost = [your.isp.relay.host]:submission
```

And then configure outgoing SASL and TLS as documented here:

http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl
http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls

Answer (score 0):

Submission port is for clients to submit messages to MTA. 
You have to talk to your provider to open port 25 for you.

Answer (score 0):

After changing `master.cf` you must reload Postfix with a command such as `postfix reload`.